# Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on **Spring Boot MySQL** example following link : **https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/**. I am getting below url when trying to access

> 2018-04-14 22:29:54.987  WARN 9572 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

[image]

**NoteController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NoteController {

    @Autowired
    private NoteRepository noteRepository;

    @GetMapping("/notes")
    public List<Note> getAllNotes(){
        return noteRepository.findAll();
    }


    @PostMapping("/notes")
    public Note createNote(@Valid @RequestBody Note note){
        return noteRepository.save(note);
    }


    @GetMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public Note getNoteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId){
        return noteRepository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));
    }


    @PutMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public Note updateNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId,
                            @Valid @RequestBody Note noteDetails){

        Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));

        note.setTitle(noteDetails.getTitle());
        note.setContent(noteDetails.getContent());

        Note updatedNote = noteRepository.save(note);
        return updatedNote;
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNote(@PathVariable(value="id") Long noteId){
        Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));

        noteRepository.delete(note);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APIs accept request body in `application/json` format, not in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Check the screenshot below -

[image: Sending application/json requests with Postman]

You need to send the request body as JSON and set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` like above in Postman.

Answer (score 3):

`RequestBody` doesnt work with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use `@RequestParam` instead.

```
@PostMapping("/notes")
public Note createNote(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {
    Note note = Note.create(map); // here Note#create method acts as static factory method which create note object from map
    return noteRepository.save(note);
}
```

Comment: @Sagar, How we can perform validation if I want to do so ?  Getting The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Note,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,String>)

Comment: @SayaliShinde, looks like you have to use `@Validated` annotation, see: https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/04/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: @Sagar, Here main concern is The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Note,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,String>). How to solve this ? We can't use map there it seems

Comment: Just map `Map` content to `Note` object, I'll update my answer shortly for same.